# If $H = \{2^k : k \in\Bbb Z\}$, show that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Q^*$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H = \{2^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, show that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Q^*$.

I've shown that the identity element can be found when $k=1$ because $2^1 = 2$. $1 \in H$ because $1 \in \left(\text{set of integers}\right)$ and $1 \in \mathbb Q^*$ because $1/1 = 1$.

Associativity can be inherited from $G$, so it doesn't need to be proven.

The group is closed because, for example, $3 \in \left(\text{set of integers}\right)$ and $2^3 = 8$ and $4/2 \times 16/4 = 64/8 = 8$, and $64/8 \in \mathbb Q^*$.

The issue that I'm having with proving that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Q^*$ is that I'm not sure how to prove that an inverse exists.

Comment: What is $2^{k}\cdot 2^{-k}$?

Comment: It would be $= 2^0 = 1$

Comment: $2^0$ is equal to $1$ @J.W.Tanner

Comment: More generally, If $G$ is a group and $g \in G$, then $H = \{g^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. It is actually the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $g$, aka the subgroup generated by $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a better way to show $H$ is closed is to notice that $$2^k \times 2^\ell = 2^{k+\ell}$$

Given that $k,\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$, we know that the sum $k+\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$ so we definitely have that $2^k \times 2^\ell \in H$

The identity of $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is $1 = 2^0 \in H$ which is what I believe you were trying to say.

Look at the comment made by nathan to get your inverses.

Comment: yes that's more like what i was trying to say, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To use the one-step subgroup lemma, one shows first that $H$ is a nonempty subset of $\Bbb Q^*$ (and since $1=2^0\in H$ and as all powers of $2$ are elements of the parent group, this holds) and then$^\dagger$ that for any $g, h\in H$, we have $gh^{-1}\in H$, but since $h^{-1}=2^{-j}$ as an element of $\Bbb Q^*$ whenever $h=2^j$, if $g=2^i$, then

\begin{align}
gh^{-1}&=2^i2^{-j} \\
&=2^{i-j}\\
&\in H
\end{align}

because $i-j\in\Bbb Z$.

Hence $H$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Q^*$.

---

$\dagger$ Yes, there is more than one step . . .